how to extract text in a mutableStateOf var? stringResource needs a context
I've got an android app with some text I want to extract into strings.xml to allow for internationalization.
@Composable
fun MainMenu(buttons: List<MenuButtonMessage>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var currentTab = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Nothing Selected") }

    Column{
        Row{
            LazyRow(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp), modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            {
                items(buttons)
                {
                    b ->
                    MenuButton(b, currentTab)
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
            Text("Select a project"))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

        Text(currentTab.value)
    }
}

This works, but I've hard-coded the strings. I can use the context actions to "Extract string resource" on the "Select a project" line and that works no problem. But if I do the same for the "Nothing Selected" string I get an error "unresolved reference" on the "context" that Android studio puts in to my mutableStateOf
@Composable
fun MainMenu(buttons: List<MenuButtonMessage>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var currentTab = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(context.getString(R.string.nothing_selected)) }

    Column{
        Row{
            LazyRow(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp), modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            {
                items(buttons)
                {
                    b ->
                    MenuButton(b, currentTab)
                }
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
            Text(stringResource(R.string.select_a_project))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

        Text(currentTab.value)
    }
}

How can I set the default value of my mutable string to a value from strings.xml?

Why don't (can't?) you use stringResource(....) like you did for "select a project"?

stringResource() requires a context. What I put in my 2nd code segment is what Android studio automatically puts in when you use the "Extract string resource" context action. (It also doesn't work so I'm not sure why android studio does this.)

You'll have to get context manually, like so:
val context = LocalContext.current
val currentTab = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(context.getString(R.string.nothing_selected)) }


Ok so I can use a local variable passed into the mutableStateOf... but I can't reference the local context directly.... seems dumb, but I've seen similar before.  I ended up using
val nothingSelectedString = stringResource(R.string.nothing_selected) then mutableStateOf(nothingSelectedString)

It'll work, but be aware that it will reload the string on every recomposition of the parent composable performing unnecessary work. @BrianHeward

won't passing the context also do extra work every recomposition? I thought the point of val instead of var was it would be optimized away in situations like this where it doesn't rely on a parameter passed to the function?

The context is retrieved on every composition but this is a single map lookup and is not a significant amount of time. The context is part of the composition local scope which is implicitly available in every composable function and doesn't affect whether the function is skipped or restarted. Ideally you would be able to look up the value only in the lambda passed to rememberSaveable() and we are working on ways to allow that. For now, capturing it as a local and referencing the local in the lambda is the most efficient.
